# OS building int 13h ah=3(hex) cf turns on and ah become B(hex) or 12(dec)

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I am trying to build my own operating system, you know, for fun...
I am on VERY early stages.... I am now trying to make a sort of installation floppy, one that copies itself to the boot sector of the main hard drive.

this is my installation procedure(I'm am using nasm):

```
install:
MOV ax,0201h
mov cx,0001h ;; my drive destinated boot sector is written on the second sector of the floppy
mov dx,0000h
mov bx, buffWrt
int 13h ;;jc doesnt turn on here
jc errorIns
mov ax,0303h
xor cx,cx
mov dx,0080h
mov bx, buffWrt
int 13h
jc errorIns1;; jc turn on and ah become B
stopped:
mov si, insMsg
call print
ret
```

I read online that when B turn on that means somthing like "bad fixed disk cylinder". What does it mean?
Btw i emulate my os on an oracle virtual machine with 64 mb memmory and a 2 gig virtual hard drive.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CHS addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector) starts from C=0, H=0, S=1.

`xor cx, cx` sets the sector to 0 which is not a valid sector number.
On the same lines, `mov cx, 1` reads the *first* sector of the floppy.

Comment: Thanks , did not know that!